# shell output to web

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I need a way to display a linux shell output on a web page. I know there are many webshells but none of them let me display a time changing output (with commands like: top, watch... ), i need a shell based network analyzer so i couldn't start and stop it each time because it need's to run continuously.
Is there any simple way to do this? I don't need any interaction with the shell, just the output of a given command.

thank in advance
Lopoc

Comment: Write the output to a text-file and display the file...

Comment: Make the command execute once, do the output and exit. Then each time you request the page that displays the output it will be refreshed. Additionally you can set a meta header in the HTML head tag that will refresh the page automatically -or- you set the refresh in your browser, if the browser supports so (e.g. Opera).

Comment: it's not so easy... a command like top, doesn't terminate, so there is no simple way to redirect its output to a file.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar and built [nubs.narf.io](http://nubs.narf.io/) - in my instance I wanted to watch output from a log in a browser.  You can install the nubs cli and do stuff like `tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | nubs http://nubs.narf.io/o/whatever.log` and view the output at http://nubs.narf.io/o/whatever.log.  Lemme know if you find it useful.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP you can use `exec()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
$last = exec('ls', $o, $r);
```

`$o` will hold the output and `$r` will hold the return code and `$last` will hold the last line of output. In general, You'll typically use it like:

```
$last = exec('ls', $o, $r);
if ($r != 0)
{
  print 'Error running command';
  exit($r);
}
else
  print implode("\n", $o);
```

`top` is an interactive program, the command will continue forever and PHP/exec() will continue waiting for it to finish. You can use `top -b -n1` for "batch mode". See `top(1)` for more information about top's arguments.

If you want a more generic solution which will work for any command, you can use `popen()` (or `proc_open()`) run from a xmlrpc script. This is a much more complicated setup though, and required some knowledge about UNIX process control. Doing this correctly is far from trivial...

**PS**: top's arguments vary from OS to OS. On Linux, you use `top -b -n 1`, on FreeBSD it's `top -b 999` (Where 999 is the number of lines to display). Not sure if this matters for you, but it's good to keep in the back of your head.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the program you launch, there should be switches like

```
$ top -n1
```

That will give you the output you're looking for in form of a snapshot.

Just make the outputting php script refresh itself after the number of seconds you need.

A popular way to do so that works in most browsers is to add a so called [Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Example: Refresh the actual page after five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to learn another language you may want to look into the general CGI module which already supports

Answer (score 0):

A [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+telnet+applet) yields [javassh.org](http://javassh.org/space/start). I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

I found a website that may be helpful in your situation - https://eggshell.pjy.us . The output of your command can be included as an iframe on your page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).